# How to fetch data with one to many relationship(mongo) with sort, limit and skip

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

I have two collections `job_config` and `list_payload` with one-to-many relationship.

`job_config` has below columns:

```
jobId
email
createdDate
totalRecords
```

`list_payload` has below columns:

```
jobId
recordStatus
uploadType
```

each record in `job_config` collection has multiple records in `list_payload` collection on `jobId`..

For ex: if `totalRecords` is 10, then `list_payload` has 10 records with `recordStatus` as either `success`/`in progress`/`failed`.

My question is how can I fetch distinct `jobIds` by filtering on `recordStatus` and `uploadType` and `email` sorted by `createdDate` with `limit` and `skip`?

Comment: You could try using [`$lookup` with a `pipeline`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#join-conditions-and-subqueries-on-a-joined-collection).